# Cart Items are not showing in cart after app restart

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux, shopping-cart, asyncstorage

**Cart Items are not showing in cart after app restart. I think its due to empty array cartItems.**

> ```
>          import {AsyncStorage} from 'react-native'
>         const cartItems = [] // 
>          AsyncStorage.getItem("cartItems").then(res=>
>            res!=null?res:[])
>            
>          const initState = { cart: { items: cartItems } };
>         const composeEnhancer = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;
>        const store = createStore(
>            rootReducers,
>            initState,
>            composeEnhancer(applyMiddleware(thunk))
>          );
>          export default store;
> ```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like `this.props.cartItems` is `undefined` which is why when you attempt to use `Array.prototype.slice` on them, it fails.

The issue seems to origin in the `mapStateToProps`, you're referencing `state.cart.items` but in your reducer, the structure seems to be `state.items`.

This should therefore work:

```js
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  products: state.products.filteredItems,
  cartItems: state.items,
});
```